# Error CS1934 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'NavigatorCustomButtons'

Tags: c#

Tengo una clase que recupero un valor con una expression lamda de un control esta me trabaja bien en VB .Net al pasarla a C# me envia este error:

Este el codigo que lo tengo en una clase en C#, en vB tambien lo tenia en una clase, espero sus comentarios:

```
public static NavigatorCustomButton MfxDtanavGetBtn(ControlNavigator poctrlnav, string pcval)
{
    // Obtener el boton de visualizar, utilizando Lambda
    NavigatorCustomButton aobtn = (from aobject in poctrlnav.Buttons.CustomButtons where aobject.Tag.ToString() == pcval select aobject).ElementAtOrDefault(0);

    return aobtn;
}
```

Comment: El mensaje te indica que CustomButtons no es una lista o coleccion a la cual puedas aplicar en linq. Revisa el tipo de dato de esa propiedad

Comment: Buenos dias, Leandro por que me funciona de esa manera en VB.NET, en este no tengo problemas, pero estoy iniciando a trabajar en C#.

Comment: No importa que en vb.net funcione, ahora estas en c# y las cosas son distintas. Tienes que validar el tipo de dato de CustomButtons, sino es un array, lista o coleccion de elementos no se puede aplicar linq

Comment: gracias, creo que te entiendo ahora un poco mas, entonces vere que tipo de datos devuelve o forma y con eso buscar otra solución. Gracias trabajare en funcion de tu consejo.

Comment: Leando disculpa la molestia, creo que tengo mala la conversion de VB a C#, este es el codigo VB original que tengo :

 Public Shared Function mfxDtanavGetBtn(poctrlnav As ControlNavigator, pcval As String) As NavigatorCustomButton
        'Obtener el boton de visualizar, utilizando Lambda
        Dim aobtn As NavigatorCustomButton = (From aobject As NavigatorCustomButton In poctrlnav.Buttons.CustomButtons Where aobject.Tag.ToString() = pcval Select aobject).ElementAtOrDefault(0)

        Return aobtn
    End Function

Y el de arriba es el de C#, puedes darle una vistaso.
saludos

Comment: en principio la parte del linq es muy parecida, pero no se que objeto es ese `ControlNavigator` ni que tipo de coleccion o lista retorna `Buttons.CustomButtons`

Comment: Es un control de devexpress, he estado probando o modificando la clase que hice, todavia no me da. Este es una barra de navegacion, flechas direccionales, botones de un CRUD, eso contiene este control y en teoria devuelve un array o juego de controles o botones.
Seguire tratando, llegue a un momento que no me daba error, pero venia null el valor devuelto.